# Represent count function in first order predicate logic

Tags: c

Given the following function which counts the number of **AlphaChar** characters in a string, how can i represent such a couting function in **first order logic**?
Note: AlphaChar is simply an **unsigned int** type

```
int alpha_char_strlen (const AlphaChar *str)
{
    const AlphaChar *p;

    for (p = str; *p; p++)
        ;
    return p - str;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Well this is not a homework to be exact, but rather part of a more general project.

Comment: "First order logic" appears to be another name for "first order predicate calculus" -- which makes this a CS question rather than a programming question per se.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `strlen` as

- the empty string has length 0;
- if the string is of the form `<string of length n><string of length m>` then it is of length n+m.

Assuming you have arithmetic in your structure

```
HasLength(EmptyString,0) ^ \forall x \forall y \forall z \forall k \forall l \forall m
    (HasLength(x,k) ^ HasLenght(y,l) ^ HasLength(z,m) ^ z = xy => m = k + l)
```